# How to validate files with ajax in Yii2?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

my rules:

```
[['passport_photos', 'oversea_passport_photos'], 'required'],
        [['oversea_passport_photos', 'passport_photos'], 'safe'],
        [['oversea_passport_photos', 'passport_photos'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 10]
```

In view i use KartikFileInput. 
Ajax validation for images doesn't work. How i can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

try add ['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']] to ActiveForm

like

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]);